# Query to compare 2 date variables/fields using mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Question 1:
Given the mySQL database table named tbl_accts with columns... acct_name, acct_xdate, acct_ydate

How to create a sql query that returns records where acct_xdate is greater than acct_xdate?

the below query returns no records which is incorrect
SELECT `acct_name`,`acct_xdate`,`acct_ydate` FROM `tbl_accts` WHERE `acct_xdate` > 'acct_ydate'

Question 2:
Possibly the dates are stored in different formats. How to test a date field to see what format the date is stored in?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 'How to create a sql query that returns records where acct_xdate is greater than acct_xdate' - you can't thats impossible - did you mean one of these to be acct_ydate? 'How to test a date field to see what format the date is stored in?' - look the tablerdefinition

Comment: Question 1: Thanks for noticing the typo. I've edited the post. Want to return records where acct_xdate is greater than acct_ydate. 
Still having problems with the query.
All dates are stored as TIMESTAMP 0000-00-00 00:00:00
Question 2: table definition is the answer. Should have remembered that. Too many projects spinning in my head :-)
Thanks.

Comment: In that case acct_ydate should not be in quotes. also publish your table definition.

Comment: Think of the table as only having 3 columns... acct_name, acct_xdate, acct_ydate.
both dates are stored as TIMESTAMP 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: removing the tickmark from acct_ydate and acct_xdate seemed to fix the problem. Thanks P.Salmon. PS - I'm unable to see how to mark your answers as the correct answer. I did vote for them to be "useful"